# How to scan in values and ignore the characters

Tags: c, arrays, char, integer, scanf

I am a newbie to C and I was looking over some questions where I pondered upon a question where we need to scan in values using the users input. Example 
1 2 3 45 6 7. So Automatically we scan these values into a 2D array.
One thing that troubles me is what If the user inputs 
1 2 3 2 3 Josh, how can we ignore Josh and only scan in the values into the array. 
I looked at using getchar and use a flag variable but I am unable to figure out the conundrum of differentiating between the integer and character.
/* This is something that I tried */

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a;
    int b;
    int A[10];

    while (((a = getchar()) != '\n') && (b = 0)) {
        if (!(a >= "A" && a <= "Z")) {
            scanf("%d", A[b]);
        }
        b++;
    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: while (((a = getchar()) != '\n') && (b = 0))  this loop never executes, does it?

Comment: To check whether a char is a digit, you can simply use the C standard function isdigit(a)

Comment: @dave_1234 The assignment `(b = 0)` returns `0`. `0` AND anything is evaluated to `0`. So the loop doesn't execute.

Comment: @dave because the assignment (b=0) should result in 0, which is the second argument of your && operator

Comment: @A.S.H Oh okie I get it thanks, BTW could you write some code using the isdigit function to help me scan cause I keep getting seg fault.

Comment: @dave_1234 it seems that you want to reject non-digit characters by the test     if (!(a >= "A" && a <= "Z"))     , well you can simply say if(isdigit(a)). However this does not solve your problem. I think the overall approach is not the right one.

Comment: http://ideone.com/Nw49yk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one good method for achieving what you want is using [scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) with the format `"%s"`, which will read everything as a string, effectively *splitting* the input according to white spaces. From the manual:

> ### s
>
> > Matches a sequence of **non-white-space characters**; the next
> >                   pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long
> >                   enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null
> >                   byte ('\0'), which is added automatically.  **The input string
> >                   stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever
> >                   occurs first.**

To convert the string to integer, you can use [atoi](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atol.3.html). From the manual:

> The **atoi()** function converts the **initial portion of the string**
>          pointed to by **nptr** to **int**.

So, if it converts the initial portion of the string into an integer, we can use that to identify what is a number and what's not.

---

You can build a simple "word detector" *for **atoi***.

Using the function [isalpha](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) from `ctype.h` you can do:

```
int isword(char *buffer) 
{
        return isalpha(*buffer);
}
```

And rewriting your reading program you have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int isword(char *buffer)
{
    return isalpha(*buffer);
}

int main(void)
{
    char input[200];
    int num;

    while (1) {
        scanf("%s", input);
        if (!strcmp(input, "exit")) break;
        if (isword(input)) continue;
        num = atoi(input);

        printf("Got number: %d\n", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

You should keep in mind that the name `isword` is fallacious. This function will not detect if `buffer` is, in fact, a word. It only tests the *first character* and if that is a character it returns true. The reason for this is the way our base function **itoa** works. It will return zero if the first character of the buffer is not a number - and that's not what you want. So, if you have other needs, you can use this function as a *base*.

That's also the reason I wrote a separate function and not:

```
if (!isalpha(input[0])) 
        num = itoa(input);
else
        continue;
```

The output (with your input):

```
$ ./draft
1 2 3 2 3 Josh
Got number: 1
Got number: 2
Got number: 3
Got number: 2
Got number: 3
exit
$
```

### About assigments and &&

```
while (((a = getchar()) != '\n') && (b = 0))
```

As I said in a comment, this loop will never work because you're making a [logical conjunction(AND)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) with an assignment that will always return `zero`. That means the loop condition will always evaluate to *false*.

In C, assignments return the value assigned. So, if you do

```
int a = (b = 10);
```

`a` will have now hold the value `10`. In the same way, when you do

```
something && (b = 0)
```

You're effectively doing

```
something && 0
```

Which will **always** evaluate to false (if you remember the AND truth table):

```
p   q    p && q
---------------
0   0      0
0   1      0
1   0      0
1   1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely wrong. I suggest to delete it.

You could use `scanf` with `%d` to read in numbers. If it returns 0, there is some invalid input. So, scan and discard a `%s` and repeat this process:

```
int num = -1;

while(num != 0)
{
    printf("Enter a number, enter 0 to exit:");
    if(scanf("%d", &num) == 0) /* If scanf failed */
    {
        printf("Invalid input found!");
        scanf("%*s"); /* Get rid of the invalid input (a word) */
    }
}
```